# Give a Counterexample if V is infinite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = nullT \oplus rangeT$ if and only if $V = null T + rangeT$.

Where $T \in L(V)$

I'm having alot of trouble coming up with an example for this. Shouldn't both cases always fail if V is infinite dimensional?

Comment: What is $T{}{}$?

Comment: If $T = id,$ then

Comment: Your title wants a counterexample, your question wants an example, by the way. (Also, if both sides of the *iff* were false, then that would not provide a counterexample to the equivalence...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I pieced together what I think you're asking correctly, you can consider the left-shift operator.

$$T((a_1, a_2, \ldots))= (a_2, a_3,\ldots)$$

where the sequence $\{a_i\}$ is in your base field.

The kernel of this map is the set of sequences with any starting term and the rest $0$, and its image is the set of all sequences. We indeed have that the set of all sequences is the sum $\ker T + \text{im }T$ but their intersection is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the space of real sequence. $T$ send every sequence to its subsequence consisting of only number at even indices. Then $range(T)=V$ so $null(T)+range(T)=V$. But $null(T)\not=0$ so $null(T)\bigcap range(T)\not=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\Bbb R[x]$, the space of polynomials in one free variable over the real numbers, and $T$ is the derivative operator. Namely $T(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$, and extend linearly.

Then the image of $T$ is the entire space, but it has a nontrivial kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one has that a linear map $f:E\to F$ induces an isomorphism
$$E/Ker\ f \cong Im\ f.$$

Regarding $Ker\ f$ and $Im\ f$ for $E=F$, one has: 
$$Ker\ f=Ker\ f^2 \Leftrightarrow Ker\ f \cap Im\ f=0.$$

The above is a necessary condition for $V=Ker\ f\oplus Im\ f$, and is equivalent to it in the finite dimensional case.

Consider $V$ to be the space of all sequences of real numbers with all but a finite number of terms equal to $0$.  Denote by $e_k$ the sequence such that $(e_k)_k=1$ and the rest of terms are $0$. Then:

$T(e_1)=0$, $T(e_k)=e_{2k}$ for $k\geq 2$ yields a counterexample to the direct sum condition.

This supplements your question and the above answers.